# How to save only date in sql and How to convert dd/MM/yyyy to sql date format?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqW0R.jpg)

When i try to save this type of date from c# to sql getting format exception Please suggest me the best way to save date to sql

Comment: do you just need to store the date in database?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because you are passing a `string` instead of `DateTime`, also you need should use paramaterized query instead to avoid SQL Injection attack and consider using the `using statement` to automatically dispose you expensive resources like connection objects. These are few best practices you should keep in mind when working with a SQL server. You can use below code:-

```
string bDate = "30/06/1989";
DateTime bDateparam = Convert.ToDateTime(bDate);
string sqlquery = "insert into BirthTable (bdate) values (@bdate)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery,conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bdate",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bDateparam;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You can also use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the date in any specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Your `DateString` To `DateTime` And Then Try Passing It To The Query, Like..

```
 String Bday="27/11/2015";  
 DateTime  dtBDay = DateTime.ParseExact(Bday,"dd/MM//yyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now Pass `dtBDay` To Your Query.
Hope It'll Help.